# Group elements to new parent node (XSLT)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transform

I'm beginner learning xsl and I need help with xsl file to transform my original xml which looks like

```
<dataroot>
    <pod>
      <id>1</id>
      <mfp>
        <type>1</type>
        <val>10</val>
      </mfp>
      <mfp>
        <type>2</type>
        <val>12</val>
      </mfp>
    </pod>
    <pod>
      <id>2</id>
      <mfp>
        <type>1</type>
        <val>100</val>
      </mfp>
    </pod>
</dataroot>
```

And I need to have new node MFPS which contain all mfp elements for one pod, like

```
<dataroot>
    <pod>
      <id>1</id>
      <MFPS>
        <mfp>
          <type>1</type>
          <val>10</val>
        </mfp>
        <mfp>
          <type>2</type>
          <val>12</val>
        </mfp>
      </MFPS>
    </pod>
    <pod>
      <id>2</id>
      <MFPS>
        <mfp>
          <type>1</type>
          <val>100</val>
        </mfp>
      </MFPS>
    </pod>
</dataroot>
```

Please help me how to solve this. Thanks

Comment: Your input has only one "pod" element(root node). But, your output seems to have more of them.(output can't have more than one root node, but that's not the case with your output). Could you be clearer by posting complete XML input and output?

Comment: Original XML looks like

[code]<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataroot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2014-02-06T11:59:36" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PodSchema.xsd">
<pod>
  <id>1</id>
  <mfp>
    <type>1</type>
    <val>10</val>
  </mfp>
  <mfp>
    <type>2</type>
    <val>12</val>
  </mfp>
  ....
</pod>
</dataroot>[/code]

There is only one root <dataroot>, and many <pod>...</pod> nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pod">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(name() = 'mfp')]"/>
      <MFPS>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="mfp"/>
      </MFPS>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It works, but resulting file is in one line. How to get line breaks?

Comment: I have found a solution, to preserve line breaks from original xml, should add:
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 2.0, you can use for-each-group

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pod">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="if (self::mfp) then 1 else 0">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <MFPS>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </MFPS>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```